# Job Schedule SSAS Command Cannot Open Database Requested by the Login

Tags: sql-server, ssas, jobs, sql-server-agent

I've tried everything I can think of and now need help.

I'm trying to run a SQL Server Agent job that has one step in it which executes a SSAS Command that processes a dimension.

When running it, the job fails with the following error:

```
<Error ErrorCode="3238395904" Description="OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error:
Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyUserName'.; 28000; Cannot open database 
&quot;MyDatabase&quot; requested by the login. The login failed.; 42000." 
Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
```

The error message is pretty clear, but I cannot figure out where the issue is to fix it.

1. This is running on a named instance that is a test copy of the main instance on the same server.
2. The named instance service for both the database engine and SQL server agent are running under the "MyDomain\MyUserName" account.
3. The "MyDomain\MyUserName" account is set up as a "sysadmin" on the instance and has rights to "MyDatabase"
4. The SSAS Database uses "MyDomain\MyUserName" as impersonation (which is the same setup as the original, which works).
5. The SSAS Command within the job step is set to "Run as" a "SQL Server Agent Service Account"
6. The job owner is "MyDomain\MyUserName".
7. I've added the "MyDomain\MyUserName" as a server administrator under SSAS security.
8. I've even added the "NT Service\SQLServerAgent" (from the main instance) and the the "NT Service\SQLAgent$MyNamedInstance" (from the named instance) as a server administrators under SSAS security.

Answer (score 0):

Geesh. It was the Server that was being used in the step calling the SSAS Command. It was still pointing to the old instance. Updating it the point to the new instance worked.